# Is there a good UITabBarController Example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a good UITabBarController example where it is **NOT** created in the appDelegate?

I would like to use a UITabBarController inside of a UIViewController, however dont know how to set the view outlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all [very well documented here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It shouldn't matter where the UITabBarController instance is created, UIApplicationDelegate or not. In a nutshell, Create all of your respective UIViewController's and add them to an array. Then assign that array to your UITabBarController's viewControllers property. Then you can simply do something like `[window addSubview:myTabBarController.view]`.

I'm just copy/pasting from the documentation here:

> You should never access the tab bar
>   view of a tab bar controller directly.
>   To configure the tabs of a tab bar
>   controller, you assign the view
>   controllers that provide the root view
>   for each tab to the viewControllers
>   property. The order in which you
>   specify the view controllers
>   determines the order in which they
>   appear in the tab bar. When setting
>   this property, you should also assign
>   a value to the selectedViewController
>   property to indicate which view
>   controller is selected initially. (You
>   can also select view controllers by
>   array index using the selectedIndex
>   property.) When you embed the tab bar
>   controller’s view (obtained using the
>   inherited view property) in your
>   application window, the tab bar
>   controller automatically selects that
>   view controller and displays its
>   contents, resizing them as needed to
>   fit the tab bar interface.

Comment: How can I access window from a UIViewController?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]. If you have several windows then you'll need to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows].

Answer (score 1):

[Here's one](http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=69&Itemid=27) implementation of UITabBarController initialized in a UIViewController.

The author also posted a github link to the xcode project.