# Best way to get the individual views into tabs

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, view, tabs

I am a beginner ios programmer and have built an app which does not use storyboards. has different nibs for different views . it also has a delegate file.

if i want to switch from one view to other i use this code within the viewcontroller.

```
self.detailController = [[[DetailController alloc]
                       initWithNibName:@"DetailController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.detailController.originalObj = nil;

SUP101AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navController pushViewController:self.detailController animated:YES];
```

also the app has the following code in delegate to show the initial view

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    self.viewController = [[[SubscribeController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubscribeController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController =  self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

i want to change the app so that each view is shown in a tab and swithing from one view to other should happen in tabs. I tried several example from other posts but am unable to get a stepwise solution to how i can achieve tab based views for this existing app. I am not sure should i add a tab controler using new file in xcode or programmatically make tabs in the view controler.Or should i start with a new project based on tabs and copy my old project files into it... please suggest.

Comment: The project linked in this answer seems to do a good job explaining it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3011262/155513.  You don't need to make a new app, just add a `UITabBarController`, tie viewcontrollers to the tab and implement the delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your modified code  , for starting tabbar controller with 4 tab

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

UIViewController *VC1=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];//set you nib name
VC1.title=@"VC1";
UINavigationController *NC1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC1];//set root of navigation controller
UIViewController *VC2=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];//set you nib name
VC2.title=@"VC2";
UINavigationController *NC2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC2];//set root of navigation controller
UIViewController *VC3=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];//set you nib name
VC3.title=@"VC3";
UINavigationController *NC3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC3];//set root of navigation controller
UIViewController *VC4=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];//set you nib name
VC4.title=@"VC4";
UINavigationController *NC4=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC4];//set root of navigation controller

UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[NC1,NC2,NC3,NC4]];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```